# Is it possible to change owner (user) on android while debuging?

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I got a problem:
I'm debugging the project which uses Google Play Cloud Saving and Google Play In-App Billing.
But I can't debug my code 'cos I have STATUS_DEVELOPER_ERROR (developer can't use the features of google play).

How to fix it?
Can I change user on my phone? I'm using the same as a developer and my phone android user. I have several account but I can't change the other by default.
Or may be does somebody know best practices?

This is very uncomfortable for a developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm waiting the answer I'd like to presend my own solution which can help to test (not debug) the application you develop:

Upload simple "Hello world" project with package name you want with

in your own developer console. Take some resourses customization, etc.

1. Public your project (you can download it from Google Play).
2. Than in Google Play in your android device set the other user as default (press menu button). //here we changed the owner of application
3. Install from Google Play the project.
4. So after that you have to create APK with code you want this the same fingerprint.//here we released new version
5. Copy apk file into device.
6. Update(install the APK) the application.//here we updated the app.

SO now you can test your application but not debug it.